# Can you make n element fill an auto-row grid

Tags: css, css-grid

Say you have a grid like this:

```
.grid-a5b1af90-3187-4dfa-bd22-71823056bd86 {
width: 800px;
display: grid;
grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, auto) 0 [end];
grid-template-columns: repeat(20<-- parametric, 40px);
}
```

this grid is a row in a css layout designed to create a "collapsable table". You have a number of data cells, potentially more than the columns allow; but no matter how many auto-rows you have you want the first one to always take up all the rows (because it is the row-label).

My working experiment is at https://experiments.bingomanatee.now.sh/grid. I am giving the first cell 2 rows as a hack but I'd like to have it span the whole rowset.

Comment: *"... but no matter how many auto-rows you have you want the first one to always take up all the rows (because it is the row-label)."* This is unclear. How do you get the first row to take up all the rows? Do you mean take up all the columns?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve